# Why is printf rounding off?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I have a simple **C** program (Compiled on the raspberry pi) Which is supposed to calculate 17.67 * 20 (which is 353.4)
The below program prints out 353. Is the `printf` rounding it off? I've tried "`%g`" and "`%.1f`"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int absolute_humidity(float temp)
{
    float abs_hum = (17.67 * temp);
    return abs_hum;
}

int main()
{
    float abshum = absolute_humidity(20.0);
    printf("%g",abshum);
}
```

Comment: Why does your function return an int?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
absolute_humidity returns an `int`
```

Change the signature as

```
float absolute_humidity(float temp);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function `absolute_humidity` returns an `int`.  It's smart enough to cast the `int` to `float` for you, but doing so truncates the .4.

Change the return type to `float` and everything should be fine:

```
float absolute_humidity(float temp) {
    return 17.67 * temp;
}

int main() {
    printf("%f", absolute_humidity(20.0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the function `absolute_humidity` returns `int`.

Change it to return `float` would have output: `353.4`

Answer (score 2):

You are converting your calculation to `int`, thus losing precision.

Change `absolute_humidity()` to:

```
// Not returning int
float absolute_humidity(float temp)
{
    float abs_hum = (17.67 * temp);
    return abs_hum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be,

```
float absolute_humidity(float temp)
{
    float abs_hum = (17.67 * temp);
    return abs_hum;
}
```

The abs_num result was being cast to an integer because you were returning an int.